# Why is /trackback appearing in logs in Joomla website?

Tags: joomla3.0, trackback

I have a Joomla 3.3.3 website. In the Redirect component I see a link to it's own directory with a /trackback added. I can't find out how this is being generated from my own website. Any suggestions?

This is an example:

Source URL:

```
http://www.example.com/alpha/beta/trackback/
```

Referring URL:

```
http://www.example.com/alpha/beta
```

In my example, http://www.example.com/alpha/beta is a legit Joomla web page being served without any problems and not generating any 404 errors when I do it. Thanks!